# If no Command-Line Arguments specified, use the directory of the command line

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments

In c# console application, I intend to get the appropriate directory. For example, let's assume that I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    }
}
```

and I do this inside the command prompt:

> FooCA.exe .\Foo\Bar

What I get is exactly the same string. So, how can I convert this to a full path?

And I would like to get the directory of the command line if no Command-Line Arguments specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()` to resolve relative directories and `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to find the current working directory (ie, the directory of the command line, as you say)

Answer (score 1):

1. `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path)` : Returns the absolute path for the specified path string..
2. `Environment.CurrentDirectory` : Gets or sets the fully qualified path of the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Path.GetFullPath(args[0])
```

This will take into account the current executing directory.  Be careful to validate your paths when taking them from user input as they could be malicious.